# PHP mySQL query returning single field as 2-element array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database

I'm using a mySQL statement in a PHP script to return the email address for a given user. You'll see the function below:

```
    public static function getEmailAddress($username) {
    $conn = parent::connect();
    $sql = "SELECT emailAddress FROM " . TBL_USERS . " WHERE username = '". $username ."';";

    try {
        $st = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $st->bindValue("username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $st->execute();
        $emailAddress = $st->fetch();
        return $emailAddress;
        parent::disconnect($conn);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die("emailAddress lookup query failed: " . $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

This returned an array with two elements, both being the correct email address. I changed the return statement to

```
    return implode(array_unique($emailAddress));
```

which solved the problem, but there has to be a better way to do this. This seems like pretty elementary stuff, and I'd like to do it right. What's wrong?

Comment: Please post the sample table data and the two element array

Comment: Does username have a unique constraint? Seems strange that you're getting multiple rows for what seems like should be a unique field.

Comment: Also, is that disconnect reached? I ask cause, it's after you `return`

Comment: $st->fetch() returns a boolean and that's what your own function is returning to the caller so where does your array come into the picture?

Comment: The username does have a unique constraint from both mysql and the validation for user registration. Also, there are only about 7 users right now, so I know it's not a duplication problem.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the return before the disconnect: it's fixed now

The table itself is just
ID | Username | Password | firstName | lastName | emailAddress | securityQuestion | rank | points

Here's a var_dump of the array it's returning:

`array (size=2)
  'emailAddress' => string 'email@website.com' (length=19)
  0 => string 'email@website.com' (length=19)`

Comment: From php.net "PDOStatement::fetch — Fetches the next row from a result set"

The return type is mixed. You can probably treat is as a boolean by putting it in an if statement
if($st->fetch())
but it can return anything
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the default response type of fetch is

PDO::FETCH_BOTH (default): returns an array indexed by both column name and 0-indexed column number as returned in your result set

I also find this quite confusing.

Specify the parameter fetch_style to either PDO::FETCH_ASSOC or PDO::FETCH_OBJ to get what you would expect.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Hope this helps